# Having very similar HTML in both IF and ELSE clause

Tags: asp.net

There is a page that has a bunch of elements like this in its code behind:

```
                    <%
    If (someBoolean) Then
                    %>
<textarea name="txtSomeThing" tabindex="1" id="txtSomeThing" style="overflow: auto;" rows="12" cols="80"></textarea>
```

Now I am introducing another `boolean` variable lets name it `someOtherBoolean` and **ElseIF** that one is true I want the same HTML as above with only one difference: adding a `readonly` attribute to it. So I copy pasted it in an else clause and added the `readonly` but VS errors on it because it think the page cannot have two elements with the same ID.
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two elements with the same Id.You can use the boolean in the attribute value like this

```
<%
    If (someBoolean) Then
%>
<textarea 
         name="txtSomeThing" 
         tabindex="1" 
         id="txtSomeThing" 
         style="overflow: auto;" 
         rows="12" 
         cols="80"
         readonly="<%# someOtherBoolean %>">
</textarea>
```